# Can't find method getFragment() in my FragmentContainerView object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, documentation

In the XML I have

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/identifications_map_view"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I would like to get the Fragment from the View. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView#getFragment()) suggests to use

```
FragmentContainerView fcv = findViewById(R.id.identifications_map_view);
SupportMapFragment smf = fcv.getFragment()
```

But Android Studio cannot resolve symbol, and if I CTRL+Click the "FragmentContainerView" it doesn't show getFragment() when i search with CTRL+F.

I know there is another way to get the Fragment but I was wondering why I can't do it this way. I guess there is some problem with the version, because I seem to have an older version of the class than the documentation's, for example there is also an extra constructor that uses the FragmentManager, nowhere to be found in the documentation.
Could it even be minimum API problem? I have 24.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

It has been added from 1.4.0-alpha01 (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.4.0-alpha01)

If you are on a lower version it won't be there.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` try this:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:name="com.example.YourFragment"
    android:tag="custom_tag"
    tools:layout="@layout/your_fragment_layout" />
```

And get this fragment instance by:

```
childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("custom_tag")
```

UPD: In some cases it doesn't work. I don't know why. Try this:

```
binding.fragmentContainer.getFragment<YourFragment>()
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated by Sam, the method `getFragment()` wasn't added to `FragmentContainerView` until 1.4.0 alpha versions.

However, as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView#getFragment()):

> This method grabs the `Fragment` whose view was most recently added to the container. This may used as an alternative to calling `FragmentManager.findFragmentById` and passing in the `FragmentContainerView`'s id.

Therefore, the alternative here is to simply do it as you would with the `<fragment />` tag:

```java
SupportMapFragment smf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.identifications_map_view);
```

And things would work just as well.

Comment: Gabriel, just TBC, `FragmentManager.findFragmentById` ALSO does not exist until 28, I believe?  (I used your method using getSupportFragmentManager - thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

For kotlin use:

```
val smf = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.identifications_map_view) as SupportMapFragment
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you might be right about the minimum api.
According to the docs to use the androidx package you need to be api 28 or higher

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx

Comment: You need to **compile** with 28 or higher, I compile with 30, that is `compileSdkVersion 30`. I was referring to `minSdkVersion 24`