# creating android library from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-library

i'm having a fragment that i want to use it as a library in other projects.
i created a library module and copy-paste all my fragment code and resources to library mode and then to use that library module i'm writing the following code in activity's xml

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
android:name="com.dhirunand.meter.MeterFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and in java file

```
MeterFragment meterFragment = new MeterFragment();
String selectedNumber = meterFragment.getSelectedNumber();
```

visually library mudule is working fine but i'm not able to fetch data from the library module

project github url https://github.com/dhirunand/meter--number-picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are using `new MeterFragment()` line then you are creating **NEW** fragment, not using one attached to `FragmentContainerView`. this **NEW** one isn't visible on screen, its just created in memory, not shown (as you haven't posted attaching code), so `getSelectedNumber()` will return default value instead this set in `MeterFragment` attached to `FragmentContainerView`

you should obtain this "real" existing and visible instance from XML by

```
FragmentContainerView fcv = (FragmentContainerView) findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainerView);
MeterFragment meterFragment = (MeterFragment) fcv.getFragment();
```

Comment: yes i understood my problem thank you., but Android Studio cannot resolve getFragment() method from FragmentContainerView. i checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018322/cant-find-method-getfragment-in-my-fragmentcontainerview-object but didn't got any soluion

Comment: looks like this `getFragment()` was introduced later, have you updated your lib `import`?

Comment: after updating the import      implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.4.0"  it's working fine.    thank you so much